# Unable to understand sql statement termination

Tags: sql, sqlitestudio

SQL noob here. I am trying to learn SQL using the following [guide](https://github.com/thomasnield/oreilly_sql_fundamentals_for_data/tree/master/databases). So here is my simple query answer for the following exercise question

> SELECT the report_code, year, quarter, and temperature, where a
> “quarter” is “Q1”, “Q2”, “Q3”, or “Q4” reflecting months 1-3, 4-6,
> 7-9, and 10-12 respectively.

```
SELECT report_code, year, temperature,
CASE
    WHEN month >=1 and month <= 3 then "Q1"
    WHEN month >=4 and month <= 6 then "Q2"
    WHEN month >=7 and month <= 9 then "Q3"
    else "Q4"
END as Quarter
FROM station_data
```

I see that if I terminate the `END as Quarter` statement with a `,` or `;`, then SQLiteStudio marks the query as invalid. Which is rather strange to me since the statement obviously needs to be terminated IMHO. Or more than likely I haven't understood what constitutes an SQL "statement" and when do we need to terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty common for queries to not need a semicolon when outside the SQL Shell. Generally they're needed, but not mandatory. For example, when launching a SQL query inside a Python script, it's unnecessary to end the query with `;`, because the shell doesn't need to know when it ends. Instead, in the SQL Shell, you are able to write the query piece by piece.

Comment: I am running these queries in the SQL editor provided by SQLiteStudio. Now talking about semicolons (or SQL terminators in general), SQLiteStudio complains if I _omit_ the `,` at the end of `SELECT report_code, year, temperature,` whereas it complains if it _finds_ a `,` at the end of `END as Quarter` . So there seems to be some kind of rule which I am unable to figure out. It is that which I seek to understand

Comment: that's strange. after indicating the last column you wish to select, you don't need a ```,```. Same for the ```END as Quarter```. Maybe it's a VSCode bug?

Comment: Is it because the result of the `case-when` block provides the last column as well as it's value?

Comment: it could be, but i'm not entirely sure